# Using Prepared Statement, how I return the id of the inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want retrieve the id of a inserted row in the database, but I don't know how to do this.

I tried to return using the SQL clause `RETURNING id`, but not works.

How I can return the id after the insertion of a row?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php

Answer (score 131, accepted):

After calling the `execute()` method on the Prepared Statement, the id of the insert row will be in the `insert_id` attribute.

```
$pstm->execute();
$pstm->insert_id;
```

Comment: But will it return a corresponding and unique ID for each execution? Top comment under [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php#102299) says that you should use `mysqli_connection->insert_id` instead of `mysqli_stmt->insert_id` if you execute the same prepared statement several times. Thought you may be aware whether this is correct or no.

Comment: This only worked for me after I set my primary index column to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: $pstm->insert_id does not contain the id!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php

Answer (score 9):

```
$newid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli_db);
```

`$mysqli_db` is your mysqli database connection. As far as I know it shouldn't matter on which way ou inserted the row (prepared statement or direct `INSERT INTO`). `mysqli_insert_id()` should return the id of the last inserted row using this db connection.

The alternative is to make another query like `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning this method also works in transactions (not so obvious).

Comment: This works with `PreparedStatement`? I got the id doint this: `$pstm->execute();` and after that, the `insert_id` attribute  has the id: `$mysqli->insert_id;`

Answer (score 6):

You need to use:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SQL Query");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Only if you are using `PDO` not `MySQLi`.