# PHP query insert_id not working

Tags: insert-id

I want to add a user to the database. Every user has an unique ID that is automatic created(A_I). If I add an user I want to get this ID. I'm trying to do this with "insert_id", but if I do this I get an error.

```
$sth=Connection()->prepare ("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES(:Username, :Password)");
$sth->BindValue(":Username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->BindValue(":Password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$ID = $sth->insert_id;
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicated question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556720/using-php-mysqli-and-prepared-statement-how-i-return-the-id-of-the-inserted-ro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.pdo.php) not `mysqli`. You need to use [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Like this:

```
$con = Connection();
$sth= $con->prepare ("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES(:Username, :Password)");
$sth->BindValue(":Username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->BindValue(":Password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$ID = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. If I do this it still comes with an error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()