# How do I get the ID of an inserted row?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this following example query, which works - I CAN insert values into my MySQL table, which also includes an unique id column. I want to get the id from the inserted row, after I execute the query. However what I get is 0 every time `($gotId=0)`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ....... ");                                
 $stmt-> bind_param("ss", ....);
 $stmt->execute();      
 $gotId = $conn->insert_id;
```

Full query:

```
$conn = $db->connect(); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table(value1, value2) VALUES(?, ?)");                               
$stmt-> bind_param("ss", $value1, $value2);
$stmt->execute();       
$gotId = $conn->insert_id;
```

Comment: Please post your full query

Comment: What DB interface are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? looks like mysqli but its better that we dont assume :-)

Comment: `bind_param` is in mysqli, in PDO it's `bindParam`

Comment: Is your sql query is correct? Please post full sql query. Its because if your sql query is wrong then it will not insert in db and return id will be 0

Comment: Have you tried `$stmt->insert_id`?

Comment: using mysqli, updated my post with full example query

Comment: @u_mulder yes does not work too

Comment: What are your $value1 , $value2 values ?

Comment: strings, the point is - that the inserting successes - there is a row created - also with a new unique id, but I can't get the created id :D

Comment: the insert ID will be in the $stmt object, not the db $conn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling the `execute()` method on the `PreparedStatement`, the id of the insert row will be in the `insert_id` attribute Only read it.

```
$stmt->execute(); 
$gotId = $stmt->insert_id;
```

[Taken from  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614828/3577946)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO .......";
 $mysqli->query($query);
 printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

> [More Info](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Can you explain Where does $sql come from ? You are mixing Object oriented style and Procedural style